# Column header sort buttons in jquery.tablesort table disappear in IE8

Tags: internet-explorer-8, header, tablesorter

This may be a really simple question as I'm relatively new to coding, but I'm using jquery.tablesorter to sort my table. So far it works just fine on Chrome and Firefox, but in Internet Explorer 8 the sort arrow disappears once I've clicked on it. You can still click on the actual column header box and it sorts the data, but the arrow doesn't show until you've clicked on another column. Then that button disappears instead! There doesn't seem to be anything about this anywhere.

Here is the code that I've got in my html file, but all of the js downloads are separate files of course:

```
 $(function() {
        $("table")
            .tablesorter({debug: false, sortColumn: 'Rank 2012', sortReset: false, widthFixed: true, widgets: ['zebra']})
            .tablesorterPager({container: $("#pager")})
            .tablesorterFilter({filterContainer: $("#filter-box"),
                          filterClearContainer: $("#filter-clear-button"),
                          filterColumns: [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],
                          filterCaseSensitive: false});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should verify that your implementation of IE8 works with the [TableSorter Demo](http://tablesorter.com/docs/#Demo).

If that works, which it should, then it is likely something in your CSS that is forcing the arrows off of the current selected column header.

Strip your page down to just the tablesorter css file if possible, and see how that looks.

Comment: Thanks Sam, will look into it. Sorry for the late reply - i didn't see this until today for some reason. Thanks!